# How can I sort a List by DateTime properties of inherited classes?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

Consider the following situation. I have a base class `Measurement` and several derived classes (e. g. `AdditionalMeasurement` and `SpecialMeasurement`) that inherit from `Measurement`

```
class Measurement {
   public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

class AdditionalMeasurement : Measurement {
   public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
}

class SpecialMeasurement: Measurement {
   public DateTime PrescriptionDate { get; set; }
}
```

How can I sort a `List<Measurement>` descending by `Measurement.TimeStamp` per default (=for all other derived classes) but if an item in the list is of type `AdditionalMeasurement` by `PurchaseDate` and if a item is of type `SpecialMeasurement` by `PrescriptionDate`?

Obviously, my try below doesn't work but hopefully shows the idea.

```
List<Measurement> measurements = new List<Measurement>() { ... };
measurements.OrderByDescending(m =>
{
    if (m is AdditionalMeasurement additionalMeasurement)
    {
        return additionalMeasurement.PurchaseDate;
    }
    else if (m is SpecialMeasurement specialMeasurement)
    {
        return specialMeasurement.PrescriptionDate;
    }
    else
    {
        return m.TimeStamp;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and desired output order?

Comment: You should write/override a `getOrderDateTime` function, thats what OOP is for...

Comment: 1) you could implement your own comparer like in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-orderbydescending-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-collections-generic-icomparer((-1)))) and put your distinctive logic in there 2) you could make a virtual method in `Measurement` that can be overriden in the derived classes and returns the desired property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont want to change the classes as [nvoigt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76930180/284240) suggested, this code is a shorter and correctly uses `ToList` and assigns the result to the original list:

```
measurements = measurements.OrderByDescending(m => m switch
{
    AdditionalMeasurement additionalMeasurement => additionalMeasurement.PurchaseDate,
    SpecialMeasurement specialMeasurement => specialMeasurement.PrescriptionDate,
    _ => m.TimeStamp
}).ToList()
```

So the problem with your code was mainly that you didn't use the `IEnumerable<Measurement>` returned from `OrderByDescending` to create a new list(`ToList`).

Answer (score 6):

The classic OOP way would be to let each class define/override its sorting criterion for itself:

```
using System;

class Measurement {
   public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

   public virtual DateTime SortDate => this.TimeStamp;
}

class AdditionalMeasurement : Measurement {
   public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    
    public override DateTime SortDate => this.PurchaseDate;
}

class SpecialMeasurement: Measurement {
   public DateTime PrescriptionDate { get; set; }
    
    public override DateTime SortDate => this.PrescriptionDate;
}

                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var measurements = new List<Measurement>() { };

        var ordered = measurements.OrderBy(m => m.SortDate).ToList();

    }
}
```

Your specific problem might be that `OrderBy` returns an ordered Enumerable, it does not order the existing list. Your call without using the return value suggests you may not be aware of this. Crank up the warning level of your compiler, that should have been a compiler warning.

You could use the `Sort` method of `List<T>` to sort your list in place, then you could put the logic which date to sort for in a `Comparer` class. That might be helpful if you have many different sorting logics.

Comment: While this looks very good, I didn't accept this answer because I don't want to modify the classes just because I need to perform some kind of sorting once.